# Bean Validation using JSR-303

Tags: java, bean-validation

We are using eclipselink as our ORM layer, and when we tried using java-validation framework with Hibernate Validator as default factory, the validation doesn't work. We are hit by this bug http://goo.gl/hQfzG.

We are trying to find alternatives to validate the beans without using Hibernate Validator as default Validator Factory. Is there something that is available other than Hibernate Validator?

Btw, we are not using spring so thats out of question I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you have against the reference implementation, but if you are dead set against it you can take a look at [Apache Bean Validation](http://bval.apache.org/). Afaik its the only other (complete) implementation to date.

Comment: Right, I checked Apache Bean Validation but thats in incubating state currently. And I don't want to have something with "incubating" in production.

Comment: The list of JSR303 implementations is ***very*** short. So I have to ask again, what in particular is stopping you from using Hibernate's implementation?

Comment: I thought I pointed that out in my question. We are hit by this bug http://goo.gl/hQfzG using hibernate's implementation.

Comment: Ok I see the problem you are having now, your options appear limited to either changing to Apache BVal, trying some of the workarounds listed in the JIRA, or upgrading WebLogic.